# Programmatically find out whether "Bold Text" is turned on in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Is there a way to programmatically find out whether the user has turned on "Bold Text" under General -> Accessibility in the Settings App?

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 8, it is possible to detect whether the user has enabled Bold Text in Settings using `UIAccessibilityIsBoldTextEnabled()` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityIsBoldTextEnabled)) and `UIAccessibilityBoldTextStatusDidChangeNotification` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIAccessibilityBoldTextStatusDidChangeNotification)).

For apps that also require iOS 7 support, I’ve written an elegant one-liner that works on iOS 7 & 8 with Helvetica Neue and even on iOS 9 with the San Francisco typeface, based on the fact that standard-weight fonts are commonly referred to as the “Regular” weight, and that body text uses this weight for readability:

**Objective-C:**

```
BOOL hasBoldText = ![[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody].fontName hasSuffix:@"-Regular"];
```

**Swift:**

```
let hasBoldText = !UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody).fontName.hasSuffix("-Regular")
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the only way in the settings and if you are creating some app you can use this code

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
```

Hope this will be useful.